# MATLAB's xlsread gives different data than shown by Excel - hidden sheets

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

I want to use `xlsread` in MATLAB R2017b to read from an externally supplied data file. Usually, this works fine for me. However, in this case I get data I can't find in the .xls file and I don't know what happened.

Here is screenshot of the .xls:
[image]

and here of the corresponding `raw` from `xlsread`:
[image]

Note that there is data in MATLAB (e.g. 'Report tem...') that cannot be found in Excel, that the columns are in a different order and that their headers also differ.

The data file is from Svenska Kraftnät, the Swedish Transmission System Operator and contains the generation and consumption of electrical energy for a certain year. You can find it [here](https://www.svk.se/siteassets/aktorsportalen/elmarknad/statistik/sverigestatistik/n_fot2013-01-12.xls).

I use the following line to import the data in question (I am only interested in the numerical data and the timestamps, but used the raw to try to understand what is going on here):

```
[num,~,raw] = xlsread('n_fot2013-01-12.xls');
```

I am sorry if this a bad format for the question or if this is a dupe, but I didn't have a clue how to make this question more general. Please feel free to suggest improvements!

Comment: There is some interesting stuff going on, as the raw data has different titles than what you see in the tables. E.g. the last column in the raw data is called `'Vågkraft prod. per CO//SWE///'` This is certainly not something from Microsoft but its nowhere to be seen in your excel, so there is something hiden somewhere. Same with some of the other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workbook has a hidden sheet in it, and it is that sheet that is being read.

To read the visible sheet, specify the sheet name:

```
[num,~,raw] = xlsread('n_fot2013-01-12.xls','Förb + prod i Sverige');
```

To view the the hidden sheet, on the Home tab, in the Cells group, click Format > Visibility > Hide & Unhide > Unhide Sheet.  Then select the hidden sheet.

There isn't a way to tell `xlsread` to only read visible sheets, and by default it reads the first sheet (hidden or not).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was possible to hide sheets. That's a good explanation! Will try it on monday and accept the answer if it works.